# Can the JVM poll for asynchronous exceptions just before entering a try-block?

Tags: java, exception, asynchronous, jvm, try-finally

Recently I read about [JLS 11.1.3. Asynchronous Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.3). I was wondering if there are any specifications about where polling for asynchronous exceptions (and throwing them) can or cannot happen. Consider for example the following code:

```java
try {
    statement1();
} finally {
    // comment
    try {
        statement2();
    } finally {
        statement3();
    }
}
```

If an asynchronous exception is polled and thrown at any `statement#()`, the other statements will still be attempted to be executed. However, can there be a valid implementation of the JVM, that polls asynchronous exceptions just before entering the `try`-block at the `// comment`, so that neither of the two remaining statements are attempted to be executed?

The JLS says that asynchronous Exceptions "can potentially occur at any point in the execution of a program", but is there a statement necessary for a poll, and if so, what exactly counts as a statement?

I have also written some test code that triggers asynchonous exceptions by calling the deprecated `Thread#stop()` method.

```java
private static volatile boolean hot = false;
private static volatile boolean state1 = false;
private static volatile boolean state2 = false;
private static volatile boolean state3 = false;
private static volatile boolean dummyOperationState = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1;; i++) {
        hot = false;
        state1 = false;
        state2 = false;
        state3 = false;

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        state1 = true;
                        dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;
                    } finally {
                        // dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;
                        try {
                            state2 = true;
                            dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;
                        } finally {
                            state3 = true;
                            dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;
                        }
                    }

                    // Replace the above code by this:
                    /* state1 = true;
                    dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;

                    state2 = true;
                    dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;

                    state3 = true;
                    dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState; */

                    state1 = false;
                    state2 = false;
                    state3 = false;
                    hot = true;
                }
            } finally {
                hot = false;
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        while (!hot);

        // Add some randomness.
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 100.);
        for (int j = 0; j < random; j++) {
            Math.sin(Math.sqrt(j * 2.));
        }

        thread.stop();
        while (hot);

        if (state1 && !state2 && !state3) {
            System.out.println("run: " + i);
            System.out.println("state1: " + state1);
            System.out.println("state2: " + state2);
            System.out.println("state3: " + state3);
            break;
        }

        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The `dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;` statements aren't really required, but it seems like the compiler makes too many optimizations without them to demonstrate the commented out code. The program as shown above doesn't terminate when I run it. My question is, is this guaranteed by any valid JVM implementation (provided that no other or further exceptions occur than the triggered `ThreadDeath`)?

When I turn the first comment `// dummyOperationState = !dummyOperationState;` into a statement, an asynchronous exception can be polled there and the program may terminate, which is exactly what happens in my tests after a few runs. The commented out code just demonstrates the case without the `try`-`finally`-blocks, which will also terminate at some point.

Comment: If there is, it has to be in the JVM Specification, but I don't see anything beyond the same stuff as in the JLS.

Comment: Your question is pointless, as it is based on assuming to have a predictable timing. You don’t know when, in terms of the stopped thread’s execution, the event happened. Hence, you can’t reason about the amount of delay between this unknown point of time and the point when it is detected and handled. Besides that, nothing in the specification says that an implementation has to use polling at all. As the previous comment says, there is no guaranty of any kind in this part of the specification, so you don’t have any guarantees. Recent JVM implementations do not even implement `Thread.stop`.

Comment: @Holger well no, the general question isn't about predictable timing at all. It's about the semantics of `try`-`finally` and async exceptions. The question is: Is it guaranteed that `statement2();` and `3` are attempted to be executed, when an attempt for `statement1();` happened before, even if async exceptions may occur at any point. My test code may assume predictable timing, however, this can't be used as an evidence for a positive answer of my question anyway. Also the question isn't about `Thread#stop()`. I'm just using it in my test code to trigger async exceptions as demo.

Comment: Also note that the action of printing the `state#` variables would be a clear evidence for a negative answer, if it happens. It also doesn't matter for the question whether or not polling is used in the implementation.

Comment: When you can’t even recognize whether the asynchronous exception occurred before or after the statement, why should there be a guaranty of any kind exclusively for the “after the statement” scenario when you still can’t rely on it, as the “before the statement” scenario is still possible and the difference not even observable? If there is any legal scenario in which the second statement is not executed, then, an implementation may not execute the second statement.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you at this point. I just noticed that I should have said "Is it guaranteed that `statement2();` **or** `3` is attempted ...", just in case it matters for your reasoning.

Comment: My point is, the expression `state1 && !state2 && !state3` in my test code can never evaluate to `true`, if the exception cannot be thrown at the comment. If an exception can be thrown at the comment, it could evaluate to `true` (if and only if the exception was thrown at the comment). My question is, is it possible? I don't know what's not clear.

Comment: Of course it can. You cited the specification yourself: An asynchronous exception … “**can potentially occur at any point in the execution of a program**”. Does the specification say anywhere that “there is a statement necessary for a poll”? No, it doesn’t. So no, there is no “statement necessary for a poll”. Will this ever happen in practice with your example program? Very unlikely. But you said yourself this can’t be used as evidence anyway.

Comment: That would be basically an answer to my question (I still don't see why it's "pointless"). However, it could also be that our interpretation of "any point in the execution program" is wrong. That raises the question, what is a "point". If there is somewhere a definition (i.e. a point is a statement), the answer would be different. I don't know if there is such a definition, hence the question.